# Non-type template parameter specialization

Tags: c++, c++20

When I compile with GCC it requires switch `(A)` to be set, while MSVC and Clang can't find `MyType` specialization and vice versa. Who is right?

```
template <std::size_t col_size, auto val>
struct sized_t2 {
    // static constexpr std::size_t size = col_size;
    // static constexpr auto value = val;
    using type = decltype(val);
};

template <typename>
struct MyType;


/* // (A)
#define GCC_CONST const
/*/
#define GCC_CONST
//*/

template <std::size_t col_size, auto val>
struct MyType<GCC_CONST sized_t2<col_size, val>> {
    using type = int;
};

template<sized_t2... Cols>
auto Test2()
{
    using XXX = std::tuple<typename MyType<decltype(Cols)>::type...>;
    (void)XXX{};
    return;
}

int main()
{
    struct x{};
    Test2<sized_t2<42,x{}>{}>();
}
```

Comment: @cigien (A) is about compiler bug that prevents this code from compiling on one of major compiler, so I can't omit it. (B) and (C) is about same topic in different contexts, there is nothing wrong to ask it is same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a GCC bug: `decltype` applied to a template parameter gives the (adjusted, deduced) type of the parameter, not of the (const-qualified) template parameter **object** to which the parameter name refers as an expression if it is of class type ([dcl.type.decltype]/1.2).  Extra parentheses may be used as usual to obtain the expression interpretation.

Comment: Found it https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99631